# How to re-enable compatibilty dialog on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, vpn, compatibility

My work uses Cisco AnyConnect for VPN client connections. When I upgraded at home to windows 8 I began getting the dialog that said something like:

Compatibility issues exist for this application

1. Run this program anyway
2. Some other option I can't recall the wording of

The first option would run AnyConnect and it would work just fine. The second option would not run the program.

This dialog also had a "Don't show this dialog anymore" check box. Well last time I ran AnyConnect I ticked that and hit run anyway, assuming that would be the default response from here on out. Well it appears that the second option seems to be default action and now I can't run the VPN client.

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to reset the "don't show this dialog anymore" question and get that dialog back.

Comment: Change the shortcut to launch the program in compatibility mode of your choice.

Comment: Have tried that. It doesn't appear to be compatibility modes themselves but whatever part of win8 detects a potentially problematic program. Click the shortcut nothing happens regardless of compatibility mode setting

Comment: I was able to change the compatibility mode for my installation of Cisco AnyConnect.  Additional information is required to understand the problem.